# Request Body search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.4.1. Here is mapping:

```
{
  "testi": {
    "mappings": {
      "testt": {
        "properties": {
          "last": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I use URI search I receive results. On the other hand during using Request Body search there is empty result in any case.

```
GET testi/testt/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "name" : "John" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things going on here:

- For both `last` and `name`, you are indexing the field itself as `text` and then a subfield as a `keyword`. Is that your intention? You want to be able to do analyzed/tokenized search on the raw field and then keyword search on the subfield?
- If that is your intention, you now have two ways to query each of these fields. For example, `name` gives you the analyzed version of the field (you designed type text meaning Elasticsearch applied a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) on it and applied lowercase filter, some basic tokenizing and stemming, etc.) and `name.keyword` gives you the unaltered keyword version of this field
- Therefore, your terms query expects your input string `John` to match on the field you're querying against. Since you used capitalization in your query input, you likely want to use the keyword subfield of `name` so try `"term" : { "name.keyword" : "John" }` instead.
- As a light demonstration of what is happening to the original field, `"term" : { "name.keyword" : "john" }` *should* work as well
- You are seeing results in `_search` because it is just executing a `match_all`. If you did pass a basic text parameter, it is executing against `_all` which is a concatenation of all the fields in each document, so both the `keyword` and `text` versions are available